# If $X$ and$Y$ are independant random variables and $U = X+Y$, $V = -\log(X/(X+Y))$, are $U$ and $V$ independant?

Tags: probability-distributions

Let $X$ and $Y$ be independant exponential random variables with parameter $\beta$ = 1. Let $U = X+Y$ and $V = -\log(X/(X+Y))$ Are $U$ and $V$ independant?
There's similar questions I found on here but $V$ is $X/(X+Y)$, I don't understand whether the $-\log(\cdot)$ can make them dependant.

For the joint PDF I got
$$
f_{X,Y}(x,y) = \exp(-(x+y)) = \exp(-u)$$ and for the jacobian I found $$u\exp(-v),
$$
which led to
$$
f_{U,V}(u,v) = u\exp(-(u+v)).
$$
But I don't know how to proceed.

**Edit:** I realise you can find $f_U(u)$ and $f_V(v)$ by integrating over $v$ and $u$ respectively, but is it sufficient to show that $U$ and $V$ are independant if the joint pdf can be written as a product of their pdfs?

Comment: **Note:** You have forgotten to show the supports for the pdf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are already finished because the joint PDF factorises:

$$f_{U,V}(u,v) = u\exp(-(u+v)) = [u\exp(-u)][\exp(-v)] \equiv f_U(u) f_V(v)$$

This means that $U$ and $V$ are independent.

Answer to your edit: Yes, [that suffices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_(probability_theory)#For_real_valued_random_variables). (See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1749635/does-a-factorable-joint-cdf-pdf-always-imply-independence) for a more detailed proof.)